# Nextjs as a reverse proxy for socket.io connection

Tags: socket.io, reverse-proxy, next.js13

I am using next 13 (with app dir), just doing some experimentation. I have an un-authenticated API gateway sitting behind (not publicly accessable) the NextJs server that has a socket.io implementation.

The client should connect to the socket via NextJs server, the Next server will handel all necessary auth checks then proxy the request to the private api gateway. Anyone have an ideas on the best way to do this?

My initial thought was to create an API route that could proxy the request

```
export async function GET(req: Request, res: Response) {
    // do some auth stuff and attach ID's
    return createProxyMiddleware({
        target: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true,        
        logLevel: "error"
    });
}
```